# Unterminated dollar-quoted string in PL/pgSQL Function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.2

I am trying to create a function to derive a code from some columns in various tables in PostgreSQL. After reading up on tutorials and the documentation for the language, I think I understand well enough to make a function that does what it's supposed to do. Unfortunately, running the query in pgAdmin or in Aginity gives an an unterminated dollar-quoted string error.

Here's the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getBreakdownCodes(cat_cd TEXT, service TEXT, report_application_cd TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    DECLARE
        breakdown TEXT;
    BEGIN
        IF cat_cd IN ('CPE')
            THEN breakdown := 'CPE';
        ELSE IF SUBSTRING(cat_cd FROM 1 FOR 2) IN ('CC','CM')                       
            THEN breakdown := 'CPE';
        ELSE IF service = 'IPVPN'
            THEN breakdown := 'IP';
        ELSE IF service = 'INTERNET'
            THEN breakdown := 'IP';
        ELSE IF POSITION('IQ' IN service) > 0
            THEN breakdown := 'IP';
        ELSE IF cat_cd IN ('DWB','HL1','HL3','HX1','HX3','ETH','IPG')
            THEN breakdown := 'IP';
        ELSE IF cat_cd in ('BVP','APN','AVO')
            THEN breakdown := 'BVP';
        ELSE IF SUBSTRING(cat_cd FROM 3 FOR 1) = 'X' AND SUBSTRING(service FROM 1 FOR 2) = 'DS'
            THEN breakdown := 'PL';
        ELSE IF SUBSTRING(cat_cd FROM 3 FOR 1) = 'P'
            THEN breakdown := 'PL';
        ELSE IF SUBSTRING(cat_cd FROM 1 FOR 2) = 'FR' OR service = 'FRAME RELAY'
            THEN breakdown := 'FRAME_ATM';
        ELSE IF SUBSTRING(cat_cd FROM 1 FOR 1) = '8'
            THEN breakdown := '8XX';
        ELSE IF SUBSTRING(cat_cd FROM 1 FOR 2) = 'DA'
            THEN breakdown := 'VOICE';
        ELSE IF SUBSTRING(cat_cd FROM 3 FOR 1) = 'L'
            THEN breakdown := 'LOOP';
        ELSE IF report_application_cd IN ('DAL','PRIVATE LINE') AND POSITION('FRAME' IN service) > 0
            THEN breakdown := 'FRAME_ATM';
        ELSE IF report_application_cd IN ('DAL','PRIVATE LINE') AND POSITION('ATM' IN service) > 0
            THEN breakdown := 'FRAME_ATM';
        ELSE IF report_application_cd IN ('DAL','PRIVATE LINE') AND POSITION('INTERNET' IN service) > 0
            THEN breakdown := 'IP';
        ELSE breakdown := 'OTHER';
        END IF;
        RETURN breakdown;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have tried to change the dollar quotes to $body$ and $func$ to see if that fixed anything, but alas, it did not.

Is there a fix for this? I am going to be running this query and function in Postgres versions 8.2.15 and 8.3.23. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated but: why are you using an outdated and no longer maintained version? (maintenance for 8.2 has stopped 4 years ago)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's what our business is running on, and those of us who are working with some database scripting in postgres have to run it in our testing environments to ensure that compatibility works. It's really limiting, but nothing that our team is able to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all `ELSE IF` with `ELSIF`. You have mismatched two forms of [`IF statement`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

Comment: I tried to change everything to ELSIF and run it again, and it had the same error. The syntax for ELSIF didn't highlight in Aginity, either.

Comment: @BJ: this does work - at least in a supported version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/328c9/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, that's disheartening.

Comment: @BJ - Your function with ELSIF is for sure syntactically correct, I have checked it in my Postgres client. Your problem is probably caused by misinterpretation of the semicolons by your client program. Try the function in psql.

Answer (score 0):

In pgAdmin the issue I was getting was slightly different than what I was getting in Aginity. Aginity by default sends queries only up to the first semicolon, then stops. So the issue was getting it to send as a single batch. (Ctrl+F5)

The error then switches to the language plpgsql not existing. However, the language does exist remotely, and not on the local environment, so I will install the language in the local environment.

The code worked on the remote (8.2.15) environment and created the function.